# Compress with gzip on firebase

Tags: json, firebase, http-headers, gzip, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to compress my .css and .js on my firebase hosted web to increase loading speeds, however I've been unable to use the firebase.json config file to correctly setup a gzip compression for my assets.

The `curl -v` command shows that no compression is performed when serving the files from the server. Also checked in the network section of Firefox Developer edition.

The furthest I've been able to go has been a load error on my browser because of my .json configuration.

```
"source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
"headers": [
  {
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=7200"
  },
  {
    "key": "Content-Encoding",
    "value": "gzip"
  }
]
```

This has been my try on the firebase settings resulting in the browser not loading any of the css nor the js.

Any thoughs?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding a header like that does not automatically gzip the response. It merely indicates that the content *is* gzipped. Firebase Hosting already gzips most files and serves them with the header when it does. Can you share the URL of the resource that is not getting compressed?

Comment: Sure @FrankvanPuffelen: `https://classics-franchise-web.firebaseapp.com/js/index.js`  Google PageSpeed shows that the resource is not gzipped

Comment: Interestingly enough some of your resources are getting gzipped, such as https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js. I'm not sure why others aren't.

Comment: Those are in a third party CDN, I think the resources that are actually hosted in firebase are the ones not getting gzipped (like index.css, index.js, myFirebase.js...)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ended up gzipping myself the .css and .js and uploading them to firebase with the headers above stated. Every file is uncompressed on my client browser, but weirdly one of them is not, downloading it compressed...

Comment: We've been trying to figure out what's happening, but it's getting tricky since you're also trying to work around the problem. For example, your index.js now shows up gzipped for me, likely because your manual efforts. Can you give me a URL that is still not being gzipped?

Comment: Sorry for that, right now there is no manual compression in any of the hosted files.
However for example css/index.min.css , js/index.min.js , css/basketball.min.css and  js/myFirebase.min.js are not compressed, among other resources.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: So, after checking the response headers of all of my resources, these are the ones not being gzipped:  When accessing **basketball.html:**   `css/material-icons.min.css` `css/basketball.min.css` `js/myFirebase.min.js`
`fonts/material-icons.woff2`  When accessing **index.html:**  
`css/material-icons.min.css` `css/index.min.css` `js/index.min.js`
`fonts/material-icons.woff2`

Comment: Those files you show are all <1K. From asking around there is a threshold before the files will get gzipped.

Comment: That makes sense, guess decompressing it is actually slower than downloading it uncompressed. Thanks for your time, your support were great!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase Hosting has a size threshold for compressing files.

All the files that were uncompressed were small (<1K), so they didn't meet that threshold.

Comment: https://drive.spext.co/static/js/uuid.js
https://drive.spext.co/static/semantic/semantic.min.css
None of the above files show content-encoding gzip, however they meet the size threshold.

Also, https://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.spext.co This says gzip enabled.

I am confused. :-/

Comment: How can I set the `size threshold` to `0`?

Comment: Where in the Firebase documentation is this `threshold` value stated?

Comment: Hey Frank, when I'm rewriting a route to a Cloud Function to respond. Do I need to configure gzip inside the cloud function? Or does it come out of the box from the Hosting system? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: these features and control are in the frontend service layer you don't have access to generally, I don't imagine you'll be able to adjust the threshold unless you setup your own service separately, or perhaps serve pre-compressed files instead