# Firebase Hosting: Minify Served Files / mod_pagespeed

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to implement mod_pagespeed for firebase hosting such that my HTML, CSS, and JS files are minified prior to being served?

It appears there are server side modules for both Apache and NGINX:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Most non-trivial textual content should already be gzipped by Firebase Hosting itself. I doubt minifying it on top of that will lead to a lot of performance improvements. If the gzipping is not happening for you, please share a URL so we can have a look. For a recent example of someone wanting this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895569/compress-with-gzip-on-firebase/47962022#47962022

Comment: It's more about mystifying the product of my work than any real load time savings. When ppl click 'view page source' I'd like them to see illegible code (like google.com does). I'm capitalist like that, or atleast I'm trying to be (profitable). ... :-) The HTML/CSS/JS serves up exactly as it is deployed to hosting. I don't wanna have to use a CI pipeline or be bothered to minify.

Comment: The minification of static asset prior to deployment might be a good use case for the new predeploy hooks in the Firebase CLI.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#predeploy_and_postdeploy_hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for Apache or nginx modules with Firebase Hosting.  If you want to minify some static content, you'll have to do that prior to deploying the content with the CLI.

Comment: Doug, I don't know which repo on github to ask on: Could I put in a feature request (via you) that this be added as an option under [Custom Hosting Behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)? In other words an option called `mod_pagespeed: true` for example?

Comment: All Firebase feature requests should go here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/