# Unable to store gzip file in google storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I would like to store json file in google storage. To save storage and network bandwidth, the file is compressed in gzip format and upload to my bucket, and set Caches-Control: no-transform to prevent Transcoding. The problem is the file stored in google storage is in decompressed format (json), and the Cache-Control in object metadata is empty.
My code:

```
const admin = await import("firebase-admin");
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const file = bucket.file(path);
  await file.save(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), 
    {'gzip': true, 'contentType':'application/json',
      'metadata': {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-transform'}})
```

The object metadata:
Content-Encoding: gzip, Content-Type: application/json. File size in google storage: 10.8kb. I manually set Cache-Control: no-transform, and use postmant & Firebase_storage plugin for flutter to download content, and I always receives content in text format – What am I missing here?

Comment: How can you say that the file isn't compressed on Cloud Storage? Can you share the content encoding of the object on Cloud Storage?

Comment: Firebase requires that files are large enough to be compressed. I think the minimum size is 1024 bytes. What are the sizes of your uploads?

Comment: I found this answer regarding compressing small files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962022/8016720

Comment: This is the object metadata:
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
My file size in google storage is: 10.8k, 
I manually set Cache-Control: no-transform, and use postmant & Firebase_storage plugin for flutter to download content, and I always receives content in text format